# Search function for a value in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, javascript-objects

I have tried to create a function which searches for the title in an array of book-objects. For some reason my code doesn't work, I have tried going through each step logically and in my mind it should be working.

```js
let book = {
  title: "The 48 Laws of Power",
  author: "Robert Greene",
  numOfPages: 452,
  publisher: "Penguin Books",
  rating: "4.5 stars"
}

let book2 = {
  title: "How to Catch a Turkey",
  author: "Adam Wallace",
  numOfPages: 40,
  publisher: "",
  rating: "5 stars"
}

let book3 = {
  title: "Glitter Every Day: 365 Quotes from Women I Love",
  author: "Andy Cohen",
  numOfPages: 384,
  publisher: "Henry Holt and Co.",
  rating: "3 stars"
}

let bookArr = [book, book2, book3];
let searchBtn = document.getElementById('search-button');
let found = false;

let bookSearch = function() {
  found = false;
  let input = document.getElementById('book-search');
  for (i = 0; i < bookArr.length; i++) {
    if (input.value.toLowerCase == bookArr[i].title.toLowerCase) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }

  }
  if (found) {
    console.log(bookArr[i]);
  } else {
    console.log("The book was not found.");
  }
}
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', bookSearch);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="book-search" placeholder="Search books...">
<button id="search-button">Search</button>
<script src="object.js"></script>
```

And lastly I'm new to this forum and also new to programming so I apologize if this is the wrong way of asking questions but I would really appreciate some criticism on my code and what I should do better. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using your browser's dev tools to debug the `bookSearch` function?

Comment: `toLowerCase` is a function, you should invoke it using `()`: `toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and it's as easy as:

```js
var book = bookArr.find(book => book.title.toLowerCase() == input.value.toLowerCase())
```

### Working Demo

```js
let book = {
  title: "The 48 Laws of Power",
  author: "Robert Greene",
  numOfPages: 452,
  publisher: "Penguin Books",
  rating: "4.5 stars"
}

let book2 = {
  title: "How to Catch a Turkey",
  author: "Adam Wallace",
  numOfPages: 40,
  publisher: "",
  rating: "5 stars"
}

let book3 = {
  title: "Glitter Every Day: 365 Quotes from Women I Love",
  author: "Andy Cohen",
  numOfPages: 384,
  publisher: "Henry Holt and Co.",
  rating: "3 stars"
}

let bookArr = [book, book2, book3];
let searchBtn = document.getElementById('search-button');
let found = false;

let bookSearch = function() {
  let input = document.getElementById('book-search');
  var book = bookArr.find(book => book.title.toLowerCase() == input.value.toLowerCase())

  if (book) {
    console.log(book);
  } else {
    console.log("The book was not found.");
  }
}
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', bookSearch);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="book-search" placeholder="Search books...">
<button id="search-button">Search</button>
<script src="object.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want only the first match, use Array.find().

```
books.find(book => book.title == 'mysearch');
```

If you want an array of matches use Array.filter().

```
books.filter(book => book.title == 'mysearch');
```

If you are using Typescript, then you can add type safety and make the search function easier to use.

```
function search<Type, Key extends keyof Type>(arr: Type[], prop: Key, match: Type[Key]){
    // For a single item
    return arr.find(item => item[prop] == match);

    // For an array of matches
    return arr.filter(item => item[prop] == match);
}
```

Then we make an interface for a book and we can easily search it while having auto-complete.

```
interface Book {
    title: string;
    author: string;
    numOfPages: number;
    publisher: string
    rating: string;
}

search(books, "title", "Harry Potter")
```

Here's a TS playground to try the code yourself. [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKYEMBOEAWAeAFQE8AHVAGkQGlUjFUAPKVMAE2UQGta5hFiyAPgAUWTAC5+pVAG0AupRKY4JSTSKUAtuii5JA2erkBKAN4BYAFCJEVmzYD0DxADE4mROhQwwAcwA2qIgwzJp29pioUCCYSGIAdMA+rMIhqJqIALyCiBbW9o4OAAJQyAC0ML5g7kHhBTDAwlDSvIjaujhZmYgARMhQmD6+PcaIkdGxwaEySipy8VBwADJwAO6omADC6GjCo5nd7bgLy2sb27vGANx1EVExSGmaM8okcl1tOrg3+TYAvtcrLcnK53J44phMOg6K0jjhUMhgc5xg9PJDEjB-MxMKlQlkck8XnMPnDAZY-kDLD5scB0BAggAhOBwTi5W6wKCBST9QZ+H4FdAgKA4dzcgZDfn2MAgTQAeWAAAV0L4EZJpZoAEYbSU2EggDX+GDIeESFDivy3KGwPxi3m+H4UyxWCAIfqIDXMzjISRMlnyLKIGThPIFDlc3o4MR0EhwKDYnrkW6C4Wi3oAKXiVHiiAASmtDX4E7d1fKlSrvYgAMwABmrid+iD1BqNJskPSbhuNGw4YHQmlQRYbVqGbYALPFqz1wn96zYQ-Yw6g2yLVohFp9uI2dlB0IOBUKRaaegArOA4JDITQhHB7qUy0vK1WIUe12f2DstjZt4DM1iN-Wdiat42MONq9AArBOU75I6VhyD8zqulAYwIiAWIBmgWC4MIHossglA9IuCYRlGjaxvGxiIWAyBwIE8T+HAvjCJEyBoVA1xAA)

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks. It's hard to see mistakes when writing on a phone.